# Blur effect in Windows Phone with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, blur, effects

I created a project Windows Phone with Silverlight.

How can I add blur effect in this image?

```
<Image Source="Images\myImage.png" Stretch="Fill">
        <Image.Effect>
            <BlurEffect Radius="20"/>
        </Image.Effect>
</Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blur isn't implemented in WP8.1.

Best route is to 'borrow' the code from the blog at http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/1/29/implementing-image-blur-in-a-windows-universal-app .

I'm not going to plagiarize his code here, but head over to his blog and check it out.  Last updated Jan 2015 so at this point its fairly recent.

Hope this helps.  Healy in Tampa